# XSS with an image file?

Tags: security, xss

I was wondering if it was possible  to do a stored XSS attack with an image.

If a site is not protected from XSS and has a field where you can upload an image file, which another user can open later. Is there a way that you can use XSS to execute malicious code?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cross-side Scripting using Exchangeable image file format (Exif)

Exif content of a standard JPG is can be changed and accepts any characters including cross site scripting code.

[image]

Depending on what Exif tag the script uses, the script can execute the malicious code inside .

So it's possible. To mitigate this issue, sanitization must be done before outputting any Exif tags.

For your reading: [**1**](https://web.archive.org/web/20151202020609/https://reedphish.wordpress.com/2015/06/26/exif-xss-using-jpeg-as-media/) [**2**](https://web.archive.org/web/20150928043648/http://www.sectorix.com/2013/12/02/exif-cross-site-scripting-php-fun/)